# libVNC implement remote desktop

Tags: remote-access, vnc, vnc-server, rfb-protocol

I am trying to implement remote desktop server using libvnc, I have downloaded the libvnc and build the library and able to run sample code. And in the example code  I can see the function `rfbGetScreen` http://libvnc.github.io/doc/html/libvncserver_doc.html which display plain background not the desktop. Does that mean I have to find some other library to get desktop and share using vnc, or vnc has some inbuilt function to do this.

Answer (score 1):

it does seem so. You need to put into rfbScreenInfoPtr::framebuffer screenshots. I've never saw any inbuilt functions yet. May be I've poorly searched.
Try SDL2. May be it will help.